# How to remove hibernate envers audit history older than 3 months without using native query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using **Hibernate eveners** to keep the audit data of several entities (**Enity_History** the audit table) and I use the default **REVINFO** table.
Is there a way to delete the audit data, that is older than 3 months from today, without using a native query?

Comment: What's the problem with native query ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you should be able to use HQL for this. For every entity with `@Audited` a new entity is created with the name suffix `_AUD`. So you should be able to do `delete from fully.qualified.name.to.Entity_AUD e where add_days(e.originalId.timestamp, 30*3) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Where is `e.originalId.timestamp` coming from, the  _AUD tables don't contain any originalId?

Comment: Do you know what a HQL query is? It's the Hibernate Query Language which works on the domain model i.e. your entities with associations and embeddables. This has nothing to do with tables. The failure for the native query is because this should be a `@Modifying` query that returns `void` or `int`: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation

Comment: I know what HQL is but is irrelevant, as I still have to write native like queries using a model instead of directly referencing the tables. I was hoping for a way to use directly the AuditReader provided in envers.